# how to pass the parameter (void(^)(NSError*))error

Tags: iphone, ipad

How to pass the parameter

```
-(void)errorValue:(void(^)(NSError*))error{

[self errMssg];
}

-(void)call{
(void(^)(NSError*))error;

 [self  errorValue ?];
}
```

Please let me know  how to pass (void(^)(NSError*))error to the method!

@All 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to properly declare a block variable first. Then you just pass it by name like any other variable:

```
void(^myBlock)(NSError *) = ^(NSError* error) {
    // Do something
};
[self errorValue:myBlock];
```

Alternatively, you can pass a block literal directly:

```
[self errorValue:^(NSError* error) {
    // Do something
}];
```